# How to fix missing cudart64_70.dll for ethminer?

Tags: mining, windows

I'm barely starting my main rig to mine. I installed Nvidia's latest CUDA 7.5, but when I run my ethminer batch file, it gives me an error:

```
program can't start because cudart64_70.dll is missing
```

I've been googling everywhere but can't find a solution. I've read it means I don't have nvidia's cuda software installed but I do! I reinstalled it several times as well to make sure.

Not sure this helps but at the end of the installation of the cuda software, it mentioned that it didn't install Nsight for Visual Studio 2012 and 2010 because they were not found on my PC. I've installed 2012 community as nvidia mentioned but it still does not detect it, and no avail on 2010 since Microsoft removed the download for it.

My setup:

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- Nvidia Titan X
- Intel Core i5 4570K
- 8GB RAM

Any ideas?

Comment: same like my rig too and the same problem that I having cudart64_70.dll is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  had the same problem. You have to download 7.0 drivers. Check ethminer to see if they are included in the folder.

Comment: Do you know why? How did you figure that out? You might want to improve your answer to add some details so the problem will be understand by future users, too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with [XMRminer](https://github.com/xmrMiner/xmrMiner-Win64/releases), only asking about version 80 `cudart64_80.dll`.

See thats the thing, the error shows the exact Cuda version you need.
Using Cuda 9.0 when you get error "cudart64_80.dll" will not work. In this case i installed Cuda 8.0 and works.